# Экранирование символов в Обероне

Tags: oberon, oberon-07

Каким способом идет экранирование символов в Обероне-07 - в частности при присвоении  массиву символов (ARRAY 100 OF CHAR) значения.

s := "x";  (* как вместо x поставить например кавычку " *)

Или нужно обратиться к кодам символов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В
[спецификации](https://inf.ethz.ch/personal/wirth/Oberon/Oberon07.Report.pdf)
языка написано:

> *Strings* are sequences of characters enclosed in quote marks (").
> A string cannot contain the delimiting quote mark.  Alternatively,
> a single-character string may be specified by the ordinal number of the
> character in hexadecimal notation followed by an "X".  The number of
> characters in a string is called the *length* of the string.

То есть, строка не может содержать в себе двойные кавычки, но вы можете
выразить их с помощью «*X*-нотации»:

```
MODULE Quote;

IMPORT 
    Out,
    Strings;

CONST
    MaxStrLen = 64;

VAR
    s: ARRAY MaxStrLen OF CHAR;

BEGIN
    Strings.Append("I said ", s);
    Strings.Append(22X, s);
    Strings.Append("Hello!", s);
    Strings.Append(22X, s);
    Strings.Append(".", s);
    Out.String(s);
    Out.Ln;
END Quote.
```

```
I said "Hello!".
```

Answer (score 2):

Экранирование в строковых литералах на Обероне отсутствует.
Чтобы в *s* поместить двойную кавычку, можно сделать следующее:

```
s := 22X; (*работает не во всех Оберонах*)
```

или (актуально для Оберона-07):

```
s[0] := 22X; s[1] := 0X; (*сработает везде*)
```

или:

```
s := '"'; (*Компонентный Паскаль*)
```

или:

```
COPY('"', s); (*оригинальный Оберон(1990) и Оберон-2*)
```

В ответе товарища Ainar-G, возможно, есть неточность. Переменную *s* надо бы обнулить сразу после **BEGIN**:

```
s[0] := 0X;
```

Comment: Спасибо за дополнительный ответ.  Но разве в обероне-07 используются завершённые зеро-символом *C*-строки?

Comment: @Ainar-G Да, во всех версиях языка Оберон (1990, Оберон-2, КП, Оберон-07) используются нуль-терминированные строки (такие же как в Си).